# How to output a Spark ArrayType column to .csv for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to get a spark dataframe into Aurora RDS Postgres.

Let's say the DF has 2 columns and looks like this:
|ID | MyArr >|

My current pipeline consists of writing the dataframe to S3 as a .csv, and then inserting that .csv into Aurora RDS Postgres via a COPY.

The issue that I'm running into is that my dataframe contains an ArrayType (of strings) column.

#### Questions:

- Is there a better approach that skips S3 entirely? or an approach that uses something like a .parquet formatted intermediary? (postgres doesn't seem to support an easy way of bulk inserting parquet files, which is how I landed on the current approach)
- Assuming the answer to the above is no, I know that I can leverage `collect_ws()` to concatenate the array, but the output format looks like this: `"A,B,C"` when I need it to look like this `"{A,B,C}"` (which is the csv array formatting understood by Postgres).  I could use a UDF, but I'm limited to working in PySpark so I'd really prefer to avoid a UDF since this file is actually fairly large.

Comment: are you limited to aurora?  you could write out to ```parquet``` or ```json``` to preserve the schema (since ```csv``` doesn't support ```array``` types) and then use athena rds to query the files stored in ```s3```

Comment: yeah I’m limited to Aurora unfortunately.  Related, those arrays that I’m collecting can be rather large (up to 100k elements), and writing them out to S3 (either as csv or parquet) is taking up to 80% of the spark application’s total run time.

Comment: your data is all string bytes so it makes sense why

Comment: I’m a spark newbie, it’s not immediately obvious why string data is particularly bad, perf wise.  Got a handy link or a quick explanation?

Comment: this isn't a ```spark``` thing; the basis is ```java``` with the ```jvm``` ... different data types equate to different byte sizes ... ```spark``` actually tries to improve this with the ```tungsten``` encoder project

Answer (score 0):

Ah, well - answering part 2 of my own question.  Will edit if anyone ever responds to part 1.

I can just use `regexp_replace()` to insert `'{'` and `'}'` after calling `collect_ws()`

Something like this:

```
        myDF \
        .withColumn('MyArr', regexp_replace('MyArr', '\A', '{')) \
        .withColumn('MyArr', regexp_replace('MyArr', '\Z', '}'))
```

**EDIT**: Upon testing, this approach is a non-starter because it massively slows down the runtime (the array can potentially be huge, on the order of tens of thousands of GUIDs).